# Bluetooth keyboard/mouse issue on Alpine Linux

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, alpine-linux, bluez

I'm using Alpine Linux with the following bluetooth related packages installed:

```
bluez-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
bluez-btmgmt-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
bluez-btmon-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
bluez-doc-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
bluez-firmware-1.2-r1 x86_64 {bluez-firmware} (GPL-2.0-or-later) [installed]
bluez-hid2hci-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
bluez-libs-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
bluez-openrc-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
bluez-plugins-5.68-r1 x86_64 {bluez} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND BSD-2-Clause AND MIT) [installed]
pipewire-spa-bluez-0.3.74-r0 x86_64 {pipewire} (LGPL-2.1-or-later) [installed]
```

The `bluetooth` service is running and I'm also able to connect and use my bluetooth headphones using the command line utility `bluetoothctl`.

However, when it comes to HID devices (keyboard and mouse) they can be paired, connected and trusted but do not create any input when pressing a key or mouse movement.

To be specific the bluetooth connection of my keyboard shows:

```
device CE:FE:50:FA:F7:83 (random)
    Name: TEX-BLE-1
    Alias: TEX-BLE-1
    Appearance: 0x03c1 (961)
    Icon: input-keyboard
    Paired: yes
    Bonded: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v04D9p2521d0000
    Battery Percentage: 0x63 (99)
```

However absolutely no key registers when pressed. I tried the same keyboard and the mouse on a fresh install of Ubuntu where it works. They keyboard also works flawlessly via its USB-C connection. I'm guessing that I'm missing a package or a specific configuration option of the Bluetooth stack.

Comment: Do non-bluetooth keyboards and mice work? Are you using seatd for seat management? What WM or compositor are you using?

Comment: Non-Bluetooth keyboards work. The internal Notebook keyboard (ThinkPad T460s) as well as mentioned keyboard via USB-C. I'm using seatd for seat managment and start (and use) sway via exec dbus-run-session -- sway .
I also followed all of the steps in https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Bluetooth especially setting up udev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I was going through the Bluetooth guide at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Bluetooth again and found the error.
As mentioned at the bottom of the guide I installed `hidapi` and loaded the `uhid` kernel module.

```
apk add hidapi
modprobe uhid
```

After that I removed the keyboard from `bluetoothctl` and paired it again. Now keys register.
To make the changes permanent I added the module `uhid` to `/etc/modules`.

Now the keyboard works even after a restart.

Comment: Odd, I don't have this in `/etc/modules` but the `hid` module is loaded. I wonder what's triggering it to load automatically. Do you have `eudev` enabled?

Comment: Yes `eudev` is enabled. However, it did not load the `uhid` module automatically. I needed to manually add it to `/etc/modules`. I think this makes sense since it is not part of the default install but needs the `hidapi` package.
The `hid` module is also loaded automatically for me.